# Pure javascript driver for mongodb that can use in xul application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, xul

I'm looking for pure javascript driver for spidermonkey to connect to mongodb, so that I can use it in xulrunner application.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Check mongo db [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Javascript+Language+Center) and read about [node.JS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/node.JS). Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, because my application use spidermonkey already, and I dont dependency on v8 and nodejs, I've read mongodb protocol, I could connect via socket and send command direct to mongodb server, but that required a lot time and word load.